# Matplotlib plot with x-axis as binned data and y-axis as the mean value of various variables in the bin?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

My apologies if this is rather basic; I can't seem to find a good answer yet because everything refers only to histograms. I have circular data, with a degrees value as the index. I am using pd.cut() to create bins of a few degrees in order to summarize the dataset. Then, I use df.groupby() and .mean() to calculate mean values of all columns for the respective bins.

Now - I would like to plot this, with the bins on the x-axis, and lines for the columns.

I tried to iterate over the columns, adding them as:

```
for i in df.columns: 
     ax.plot(df.index,df[i])
```

However, this gives me the error: "float() argument must be a string or number, not 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'

Therefore, I assume it wants the x-axis values to be numbers or strings and not intervals. Is there a way I can make this work?
To get the dataframe containing the mean values of each variable with respect to bins, I used:

```
bins = np.arange(0,360,5)
df = df.groupby(pd.cut(df[Dir]),bins)).mean()
```

Here is what df looks like at the point of plotting - each column includes mean values for each variable 0,1,2 etc. for each bin, which I would like plotted on y-axis, and "Dir" is the index with bins.

```
                        0            1            2            3          4          5
Dir                                                                        
(0, 5]          37.444135  2922.848675  3244.325904  4203.001446  36.262371  37.493497
(5, 10]         42.599494  3248.194328  3582.355759  4061.098517  36.351476  37.148341
(10, 15]        47.277694  2374.379517  2709.435714  2932.064076  36.537377  36.878293
(15, 20]        52.345712  2626.774240  2659.391040  3087.324800  36.114965  36.603918
(20, 25]        57.318976  2207.845000  2228.002353  2811.066176  36.279392  37.165979
(25, 30]        62.454386  2436.117405  2839.255696  3329.441772  36.762896  37.861577
(30, 35]        67.705955  3138.968411  3462.831977  4007.180620  36.462313  37.560977
(35, 40]        72.554786  2554.552620  2548.955581  3079.570159  36.256386  36.819579
(40, 45]        77.501479  2862.703066  2965.408491  2857.901887  36.170788  36.140976
(45, 50]        82.386679  2973.858188  2539.348967  2000.606359  36.067776  37.210645
```

Comment: Added to original post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have multiple options, we can obtain the middle of the bin using as shown below. You can also access the left and right side of the bins, as described [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html). Let me know if you need any further help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': np.random.uniform(low=0, high=10, size=10), 'y': np.random.exponential(size=10)})
bins = range(0,360,5)
df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['x'], bins)
agg_df = df.groupby(by='bin').mean()

# this is the important step. We can obtain the interval index from the categorical input using this line.
mids = pd.IntervalIndex(agg_df.index.get_level_values('bin')).mid

# to apply for plots:
for col in df.columns:
    plt.plot(mids, df[col])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It seems my index is actually a "CategoricalIndex," so I am receiving the error "CategoricalIndex" object has no attribute 'bin'. It seems when I do groupby().mean(), it returns this df with categorical index.

Comment: Could you put the code for the cut, grouping, and aggregation? It would help me in finding a solution for your problem!

Comment: I think there's only one relevant prior step, which is how I arrive at the summarized mean values. Added above to main post now

Comment: I adjusted the code to cast the categorical data into interval data. Could you confirm that the solution worked out, or if you need any additional information?

Comment: The code works to plot the midpoints on x axis but still doesn't show intervals on the x axis.

Comment: Solution found using ax.set_xticks(mids.values, agg_df.index.values,rotation='vertical')